# SSIS error 0xC0011008 Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application.LoadPackage

Tags: .net, sql-server, ssis, dts

I'm calling `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application.LoadPackage` from a `.net(V4.0)` application to load SSIS package that are installed into the local disk of a VM Windows Server 2016. I run this code from `Visual Studio 2017` Community in debug mode to test my integrations. 
The packages SSIS were created in Visual Studio 2010 and I migrated them to be compatible with Visual Studio 2017. They integrate data into a SQL server 2017. If I simply execute my packages from my `SSIS` solution it works perfectly, but when I load them within my other C# code using `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application.LoadPackage`, I get the following error:

> The package failed to load due to error 0xC0011008 "Error loading from XML. No further detailed error information can be specified for this problem because no Events object was passed where detailed error information can be stored.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.

By the way, is not a code problem as it works perfectly in my actual environment(`Windows Server 2012 R2` targeting `SQL Server 2017`) with the exactly same code. I think is more version compatibility related or server configuration.

Comment: Have you checked that the correct version of the `Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll` is installed on the VM? We had a similar problem when testing through environments

Comment: Hello Matt, how do i know what is the correct version and how do I check that it is correctly installed? Actually I kept the same version in the project has it was added with Nuget, but I don't know which version I must upgrade to

Comment: So Integration Services is a server component and isn't redistributeable, so you've added the reference with Nuget but you need to run the install for the Client Tools SDK on the VM

Comment: I have installed SSDT on my VM through this url https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017. Is Client Tools Sdk something different? Where can I get it? My VM where I run the process doesn't have any SQL server instance installed.

Comment: Yes, the SDK is a feature within the SQL Server installer. You will need to run that on your VM. I'm trying to find a picture for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem upgrading my project to version 4.6 of the .net framework.
Also as Matt said, you have to install the SDK tools also.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

XML error as mentioned above is because of the version issue.
Answer:

1. right click on the report and go to the properties.(not the individual report, the one right below the solution.)
2. On the debug configuration-> if the 64-bit is true set it to false and vice versa.
3. It should work now. If not, please restart the VS.

Thank you.